# How to change xdebug key binding in Sublime Text?

Tags: xdebug, sublimetext3

I want to change the key bindings for XDebug plugin in Sublime Text 3.  How I can change the key binding for **Run**, **Step over**, **Step into**, **Step out**, etc.?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*This answer is a more complete [answer from user2968356](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142617/how-to-change-xdebug-key-binding-in-sublime-text/21160426#21160426).*

To complete this answer, the `.sublime-package` file is an archive, so it can be decompressed using a ZIP utility. It's not necessary to edit the `Default.sublime-keymap` in the package, we can copy the key bindings and add it modified to `Default.sublime-keymap` available from **Preferences** -> **Key Bindings - User** in Sublime Text.

And to provide a shortcut, here's the default key binding of XDebug package, modify at will:

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+f8"], "command": "xdebug_breakpoint"},
{"keys": ["shift+f8"], "command": "xdebug_conditional_breakpoint"},
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+f5"], "command": "xdebug_continue", "args": {"command": "run"}},
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+f6"], "command": "xdebug_continue", "args": {"command": "step_over"}},
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+f7"], "command": "xdebug_continue", "args": {"command": "step_into"}},
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+f8"], "command": "xdebug_continue", "args": {"command": "step_out"}},
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+f9"], "command": "xdebug_session_start"},
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+f10"], "command": "xdebug_session_stop"},
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+f11"], "command": "xdebug_layout", "args": {"keymap" : true}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Preferences -> Browse Packages...` in the sublime menu.

This will open the `Packages` folder. Go back one folder and you should see another folder called `Installed Packages`.

Find the `.sublime-package` for xdebug usually named accordingly to the package name you installed via package control.

Inside you find a `Default.sublime-keymap` file that holds all the key bindings.

Change to your needs, save and restart sublime.

Cheers, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For Max users, you may want to replace 'ctrl' with 'super', which is the command key. Followings are my settings:

```
[
    {"keys": ["super+f16"], "command": "xdebug_breakpoint"},
    {"keys": ["shift+f16"], "command": "xdebug_conditional_breakpoint"},
    {"keys": ["super+shift+f5"], "command": "xdebug_continue", "args": {"command": "run"}},
    {"keys": ["super+f13"], "command": "xdebug_continue", "args": {"command": "step_over"}},
    {"keys": ["super+f14"], "command": "xdebug_continue", "args": {"command": "step_into"}},
    {"keys": ["super+f15"], "command": "xdebug_continue", "args": {"command": "step_out"}},
    {"keys": ["super+shift+f9"], "command": "xdebug_session_start"},
    {"keys": ["super+shift+f17"], "command": "xdebug_session_stop"},
    {"keys": ["super+shift+f18"], "command": "xdebug_layout", "args": {"keymap" : true}}
]
```